# Concatenate duplicate values by specific values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

On Excel, I am trying to put in a single line both colors separated by semicolon. If the cod and name are equal it must concatenate in just a single line both colors.

What I have:

[image]

What I am trying to get:

[image]

Comment: May I know why keeping "Color" column? Only because Yellow was the first (found) one?

Comment: @FaneDuru the goal is to have a single line with both colors, because the rest is duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the next code. It uses a dictionary (loaded from an array) to extract unique codes, then processes its content:

```
Sub CondenseFruitsTable()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, mtch, dict As Object, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on column A:A
 
  arr = sh.Range("A1:C" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)
    Else
        mtch = Application.match(arr(i, 3), Split(Split(dict(arr(i, 1)), "|")(1), ";"), 0)
        If IsError(mtch) Then 'if the color does  not already exist:
            dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) & ";" & arr(i, 3)
        End If
    End If
  Next i
  
  'redim the final array to also include the header:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To 3)
  
  arrFin(1, 1) = arr(1, 1): arrFin(1, 2) = arr(1, 2): arrFin(1, 3) = arr(1, 3)
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
        arrFin(i + 2, 1) = CStr(dict.keys()(i))
        arrFin(i + 2, 2) = Split(dict.Items()(i), "|")(0)
        arrFin(i + 2, 3) = Split(dict.Items()(i), "|")(1)
  Next i
  'drop the result and format a little:
  With sh.Range("F1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 3)
        .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value2 = arrFin
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Rekcs This returns non-distinct lists of colors if there are duplicate colors, or if `Cod` matches but `Name` does not.

Comment: Yup, @Rekcs, in your post you have mentioned to take both `Cod` and `Name`.

Comment: @Rekcs Is it possible to have different codes for the same Name? Shouldn't they be unique pairs? I considered the code as key, in the name may some spelling mistakes appear...

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya Who said that the above code does not "take" both of them? But based on unique codes...

Comment: @FaneDuru Sir, it does takes but if the `Cod` and `Name` doesnt match, like if the `Cod` is `0010` and `Name` is `Orange` then it concats with Banana and not showing a different row with `Orange`

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya Of course, not! The main purpose of using a code is to be unique. That's why I used it as a dictionary key. The misspelled name shouldn't matter. At least, in my opinion... I asked the OP about the aspect and he did not say anything. Otherwise, it is very simple to adapt the code to build the key by concatenation of the first two columns. I've chosen this way on purpose...

Comment: @FaneDuru Sir, no offense, your code works, but if you mind adding the one which takes both. Because I think, that is what it is needed, we know most of the times, OP have something in their post and they need something else. Usually, they are not very clear with their end goal.

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya I may agree that they may need something else, but in my opinion it will be wrong to have different names for the same code. This is the saint meaning of the code. **To be unique**... But, if he will need something else I suppose he will be unsatisfied after testing it and will require a different variant.

Comment: @Rekcs I do not know how the range to be processed is loaded and it is possible to have **the same color for the same code/name**. I adapted the above code to previously check if the specific iterated color already exists in the semicolon separated list. It was above a pertinent observation about this aspect... If not the case, nothing wrong will happen with the code.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in Power Query, using the Table.Group method and a custom aggregation.

*Based on your comment in your question, I assumed you did not want to retain the original Color column (first row only), but that is easily added back if not the case.*

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table17"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Cod", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Color", type text}}),

//Group by Cod amd Name, then aggregate by combining the colors
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Cod","Name"}, {
        {"Colors", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(_[Color]),";")}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, if you can add the `Color` Column as well, if its not too much to ask, will be helpful.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I do not believe he wants that, but if he does, he can just add an aggregation `{"1st Color", each [Color]{0}, type text},`

Comment: Ok, thats great !!

Answer (score 2):

### Uniquify Table Data

[image]

```vb
Sub UniquifyTable()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const UNI_COL As Long = 1 ' or 2
    Const JOIN_COL As Long = 3
    Const JOIN_DELIMITER As String = "; "
    Const NEW_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "Color (sep. Semicolon)"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        
        ' Unique to dictionary.
        
        Dim Data: Data = .Columns(UNI_COL).Value
        Dim uDict As Object: Set uDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        uDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        Dim srCount As Long: srCount = .Rows.Count
        
        Dim r As Long
        
        For r = 2 To srCount ' skip headers
            If Not uDict.Exists(Data(r, UNI_COL)) Then
                Set uDict(Data(r, UNI_COL)) = New Collection
            End If
            uDict(Data(r, UNI_COL)).Add r
        Next r
        
        ' Source to array.
        
        Dim scCount As Long: scCount = .Columns.Count
        Data = .Value
        
        ' Overwrite array with results.
        
        ' Resize (add column).
        ReDim Preserve Data(1 To srCount, 1 To scCount + 1)
        Data(1, scCount + 1) = NEW_COLUMN_TITLE
        
        Dim jDict As Object: Set jDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        jDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        
        Dim Key, Item, c As Long, IsNewRow As Boolean
        r = 1 ' skip headers
        
        ' Populate top.
        For Each Key In uDict.Keys
            r = r + 1
            For Each Item In uDict(Key)
                If jDict.Count = 0 Then
                    For c = 1 To scCount
                        Data(r, c) = Data(Item, c)
                    Next c
                End If
                If Not jDict.Exists(Data(Item, JOIN_COL)) Then
                    jDict(Data(Item, JOIN_COL)) = Empty
                End If
            Next Item
            Data(r, c) = Join(jDict.Keys, JOIN_DELIMITER)
            jDict.RemoveAll ' reset for next iteration
        Next Key
        
        ' Clear bottom.
        For r = r + 1 To srCount
            For c = 1 To scCount
                Data(r, c) = Empty
            Next c
        Next r
        
        ' Write back to worksheet.
        
        .Resize(, c).Value = Data
        .Columns(c).AutoFit
        
    End With

End Sub
```